# ASP.NET MVC custom _Layout.cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Visual Studio creates a defualt _Layout.cshtml
And I am trying to make different design; however, when the RenderSection() \code is deleted, the browser shows an error. It does not load. Can anyone show help me how to do it.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code? Hard to trouble shoot without seeing what you've tried.

Comment: Is the view still trying to define the section for which you deleted the RenderSection? That's probably why.

Answer (score 2):

If your view is trying to define a section such as:

```
@section Hello
{
    <p>Hello</p>
}
```

And your _Layout never renders it:

```
@RenderSection("Hello")
```

Then you will get an exception such as:

"The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml": "Hello"."

You must call RenderSection for all sections that your views define, or remove the sections from the view.

Comment: Or make it optional `@RenderSection("Hello", required: false)`

Comment: Ah, yes. Which I've done several times. Can't believe I forgot to mention that. Thanks @Jasen.